# Button not enabled when added programmatically to collectionviewcell

Tags: swift, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell

When I add a button programmatically to the custom UICollectionViewCell class, it is not clickable and will not run the function I attached to it.

I have tried these so far:

- [Button inside CollectionView not clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49615125/button-inside-collectionview-not-clickable)
- [Swift - UIButton in UICollectionViewCell not clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42504935/swift-uibutton-in-uicollectionviewcell-not-clickable)

but did not get any luck.

In my cell Class, I have:

```
let toggleButton: UIButton = {
    let tb = UIButton(type: .custom) as UIButton
    tb.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    tb.setTitle("Example", for: .normal)
    tb.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.customFont(name: "InterUI-Medium", size: 18)
    tb.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.36, green:0.69, blue:0.55, alpha:1.0)
    tb.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    tb.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    tb.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.4
    tb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tb.addTarget(self, action: #selector(topButtonTouched), for: .touchUpInside)
    return tb
}()
```

and

```
func setupView() {
    self.addSubview(toggleButton)

    let menuAndToggleConstraints = [
        toggleButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
        toggleButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -100,
        toggleButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
    ]
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(menuAndToggleConstraints)
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}
```

to setup the button in the cell. I have tried self.isUserInteractionEnabled to see if there are any conflicts but it does not resolve anything. I have one other gesture recognizer in the cell and have tried without it and the button is still not clickable.

Edit:
Here is my delegate and my function that calls the collectionView to change the size at indexPath:

```
weak var delegate: ExpandedCellDelegate?
public var indexPath: IndexPath!

@objc func topButtonTouched(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("hello")
    if let delegate = self.delegate{
        delegate.topButtonTouched(indexPath: indexPath)
    }
}
```

I made sure to set the delegate and indexPath as self in cellForRow function in CollectionView class as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40825981/10741339).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41456441/how-to-add-uibutton-action-in-a-collection-view-cell/41456496#41456496

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make the button work by putting this:

```
tb.addTarget(self, action: #selector(topButtonTouched), for: .touchUpInside)
```

into the setupView() method like so:

```
func setupView() {
    self.addSubview(toggleButton)
    toggleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(topButtonTouched), for: .touchUpInside)

    let menuAndToggleConstraints = [
        toggleButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
        toggleButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -100,
                                               toggleButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
            ]
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(menuAndToggleConstraints)
}
```

Not sure if it's correct but it works.